# Google Apps Script: How to share calendar with another user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am trying to share google calendars of a user in domain with another user in other domain using google apps script and OAuth authorization. But i am not able to perform this task. I fetched all the calendars events of user but couldn't do the sharing.
Any solution would be appreciated.
Thank You

Solution of this problem is here:

```
function calenderSharing(user1,user2){

    var scope = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/';
    var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('calenders', scope);
    var rawXml= "<entry xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>"+
      "<category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessRule'/>"+
      "<gAcl:scope type='user' value='"+user2+"'></gAcl:scope>"+
      "<gAcl:role value='http://schemas.google.com/gCal/2005#owner'>  </gAcl:role></entry>"
    fetchArgs.method = 'POST';
    fetchArgs.payload = rawXml
    fetchArgs.contentType = 'application/atom+xml';

    try{
         var url='https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/'+user1+'/acl/full'        
         var urlFetch=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs)                         //Giving Permission To personal account as a owner
       }
    catch(err){
        var err1=err.toString()
        var ex='Exception: Request failed for  returned code 302'
        if(ex==err1.split('.')[0]){
              var tempCalenderUrl=[]
              tempCalenderUrl.id = err1.split('<A HREF="')[1];
              tempCalenderUrl.id = tempCalenderUrl.id.split('"')[0];
              var url=tempCalenderUrl.id
              try{
                  var urlFetch=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs)   
                 }
              catch(err){}
         }         
     }
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(consumerKey);
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumerSecret);
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Comment: If you want, you can answer your own question and select it.  This will help future visitors find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Script you can't. The Calendar Script API does not support sharing of calendars (at this time). 
Your workaround might be to get the calendar ID using script and using UrlFetch (with OAuth) to call the Google Calendar API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/. Ensure you authenticate, perform a 'get' to get the calendar based on the ID you retrieved from your script, get the ACL and add a new entry to share with the user outside your domain.

Not an easy solution. Sorry.

Comment: Calendar sharing is possible through Calender API. I updated my question with answer. Have a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make an App that would allow this user to simply subscribe to this new calendar instead? 
All the necessary tools are in the gas calendar service-
Here is an example of [such an application](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/a-calendar-subscriber-app)